# ¿Cómo implemento el evento onClickListener en una lista hecha con RecyclerView?

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde utilizo un navigation drawer que contiene una serie de fragments con una lista, para ello he utilizado un RecyclerView, al seleccionar un ítem de la lista me lleve a otro fragment con texto en su contenido.

Quisiera saber cómo implemento el evento onClickListener teniendo en cuenta los siguientes códigos java.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        agregarToolbar();

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            prepararDrawer(navigationView);
            // Seleccionar ítem por defecto
            seleccionarItem(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
        }
    }

    private void agregarToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            // Agregar ícono del drawer toggle
            ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu);
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void prepararDrawer(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                seleccionarItem(menuItem);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void seleccionarItem(MenuItem itemDrawer) {
        Fragment fragmentoGenerico = null;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (itemDrawer.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_inicio:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoInicio();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap1:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap1();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap2:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap2();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap3:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap3();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap4:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap4();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap5:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap5();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap6:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap6();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap7:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap7();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap8:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap8();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap9:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap9();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap10:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap10();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap11:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap11();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cap12:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoCap12();
                break;
        }

        if (fragmentoGenerico != null) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor_principal, fragmentoGenerico).commit();
        }

        // Setear el título actuar
        setTitle(itemDrawer.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

FragmentoCap1.java

```
public class FragmentoCap1 extends Fragment {
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayout;

    public FragmentoCap1() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_cap1, container, false);

        RecyclerView reciclador = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
        linearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        reciclador.setLayoutManager(linearLayout);

        AdaptadorListadoCap1 adaptador = new AdaptadorListadoCap1();
        reciclador.setAdapter(adaptador);
        reciclador.addItemDecoration(new DecoracionLineaDivisoria(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }
}
```

AdaptadorListadoCap1.java

```
public class AdaptadorListadoCap1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorListadoCap1.ViewHolder> {
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Campos respectivos de un ítem
        public TextView titulo;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tituloListado);
        }
    }

    public AdaptadorListadoCap1() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Articulos.CAP1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_listado, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Articulos item = Articulos.CAP1.get(i);

        viewHolder.titulo.setText(item.getTitulo());
    }
}
```

Articulos.java

```
public class Articulos {
    private int titulo;

    public Articulos(int titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public static final List<Articulos> CAP1 = new ArrayList<Articulos>();

    static {
        CAP1.add(new Articulos(R.string.titulo_art1));
        CAP1.add(new Articulos(R.string.titulo_art2));
        CAP1.add(new Articulos(R.string.titulo_art3));
        CAP1.add(new Articulos(R.string.titulo_art4));
        CAP1.add(new Articulos(R.string.titulo_art5));
        CAP1.add(new Articulos(R.string.titulo_art6));
    }

    public int getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }
}
```

DecoracionLineaDivisoria.java

```
public class DecoracionLineaDivisoria extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private Drawable lineaDivisoria;

    public DecoracionLineaDivisoria(Context context) {
        lineaDivisoria = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.linea_divisoria);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + lineaDivisoria.getIntrinsicHeight();

            lineaDivisoria.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            lineaDivisoria.draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar un OnItemClick listener tienes que seguir lo siguiente:

1. Crea una interfaz con ese nombre que tenga un metodo que reciba 2 parametros (view y position).
2. Declaras la interfaz en el Adapter y se lo asignas a la vista en la clase Holder.
3. Mandas a llamar la interfaz en el Activity/Fragment donde instancias el adaptador.

Para que puedas entender con un ejemplo te dejo el siguiente [link](https://gist.github.com/moizest89/ad5936a93368e609b348867d3c1f2a3e) donde puedes seguir detenidamente lo dicho arriba.